# Disasters to prompt the bettering of civilisation

Tags: society, natural-disasters, future, cataclysms

so, being a cynic as well as a speculative biologist and all-round sci-if fan, I believe that the scenario I want to reach in my project, where humanity has restored the Earth’s biosphere and climate, and major governments been prompted to invest in the Long-term settlement and terraforming of other planets, could not arise out of our own good will. I need some form of cataclysm or near-cataclysmic event to prompt humanity to smarten itself up, as it were, but am stumped as to what event could cause this.

So, what apocalyptic event could prompt the bettering of civilisation as a whole? Specifically, the healing of the planet, adoption of renewable energy resources, and spearheading the drive into outer space. I should note that:

A: for preference, an outside influence, (I.E a meteor impact) is preferred, though an anthropogenic distaste will do.

B: if it is anthropogenic, it cannot be caused by a Nuclear war, AI or nanotechnological disasters, the former because I used this excuse in a former project, and the latter two because nanotech and AI are major features in the project.

Comment: "Speculative biologist"  is it just me being an overly warped cynic with a twisted imagination or does that sound like code for something involving other species that really shouldn't to anyone else? 

Comment: I wish SE:WB could support this question because I really like it. (Q's asking for idea-generation/infinite list of options are closed here.) Could you ask it at Reddit on r/worldbuilding? (Or alternatively, r/goodworldbuilding)

Comment: That, or narrow-in on a particular idea and explore its feasibility (in achieving the desired outcome).

Comment: "Bettering the civilization as a whole" depends on the point of view of the person who appreciates the civilization. And minus one for the meaningless phrase "restoring Earth's climate". Restoring it to what? Last Glacial Maximum? Holocene Thermal Optimum? Second century BCE? Fourteenth century CE? It's not as if Earth's climate was stable before 1990 and then it suddenly started to change. (Yes, human activities make it change faster than it would have changed on its own; but change it did.) And please explain why the climate in the fifteenth century was "better" than the climate in the 21st.

Comment: Realistically? Any civilization collapse leading to dark age (well, at least return to conditions as nasty as before industrial revolution). The key part would be reintroduction of harsh Darwinian selection favouring IQ that would last for at least half millennium. With higher average score next time you should get more cooperation and more long term planning than this time.

Answer (score 2):

### Collapse of Globalization

No one country has the infrastructure and resources to maintain all of its own wants and needs.  The gluttony of modern civilization has made every nation reliant on other countries to maintain their standard of living.  This mean that it only takes a small breakdown in the global supply chain to create a heap of motivation to change.

The Russian/Ukraine war underlines this point very well.  Since it started, this relatively isolated conflict has caused massive waves of economic consequences around the whole world.  Most notably, it's forced Europe (a rich but fossil fuel poor part of the world) to double time their RnD into renewable and fusion energy.  If the war never happened, they could have just kept burning Russian Gas for decades to come, but now they are on a very real deadline to make it happen.  So using this as the blueprint, you could have a number of relatively small, non-nuclear wars force a large part of the world economy to go sustainable as fracturing political ties force the need for economic independence in resource scarce locales.

Once a large part of the world is fully invested in sustainable energy, recycling, etc. the advanced practices that made it possible will come into direct conflict with less sustainable practices.  Right now we have limited options and technology for sustainable power, agriculture, etc... but if these technologies were forced to rapidly advance by several decades while more traditional technologies stagnated, they would begin to dominate the traditional technologies in a good old fashioned capitalist style until they become the globally dominate way of doing business.

Comment: "No one country has the infrastructure and resources to maintain all of its own wants and needs" I think I'm going to need you to justify that sweeping generalisation and rather broad unsupported assumption for me somewhat, for a start there are very few countries indeed that aren't capable of providing for their own 'needs' as I understand that word so perhaps you could start with that be clearly defining what you mean by that?

Comment: @Pelinore I said "**wants** and needs", there is a difference.  While a country like the USA for example could be cut off from all global trade and not be at risk of major food or power shortages, it would still be cut off from a lot of things like various manufactured products, off-season agricultural products etc. Quality of life would be significantly impacted.

Comment: Hmm .. the US probably 'would' be at risk of major power shortages right now so *possibly* a bad example  but they do actually have the natural resources to avoid that and he risk is largely self made by current administration, so good example  .. so the *needs* is superfluous to what you meant then and wants are the only things at risk in your estimation, most of those can also be met by most countries but the risk to some of them, particularly in the short term with the way our global supply chains are currently set up, is greater yes.

Comment: @Pelinore I included needs because for most countries, there are real for true needs that can't be meet without globalization.  If all trade between countries where to fail, then the fertilizer/pesticide/herbicide trade would fail resulting in over a 50% reduction in global food production.  You'd also cut off a lot of nations from water purification supplies, refrigeration systems, medical supplies, fossil fuels, etc.  Millions if not billions of people could die from the resulting famine, disease, exposure, and wars/genocides of desperation.

Comment: Well I think I can guess who's YouTube you've been watching  not sure that I believe the apocalypse will come just because we lose a bit of interconnectivity in our nation's, though the shock it would cause is definately one of the strongest arguments for why we should never have allowed globalism to go as far as it has, the atrophy to individual nations infrastructure for so many things as they became reliant on global supply chains is the main self inflicted cause of any problems that would arise and a strong argument to reverse globalisation and rebuild national infrastructures 

Answer (score 2):

**Alien Invasion**

[image]

The only thing that will bring humans together is killing something else. An alien invasion is likely to do that or, at least, the threat of an alien invasion.

Aliens start terraforming Earth? Humans have to develop technology to undo the changes which also cleans up our mess.

After being defeated, humans still have to work together in case they come back. They use said technology to terraform Mars and possibly other planets outside the solar system.